# Why isn't setVisibility working on Android ProgressBar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

It would be nice if the ProgressBar could be made to go away until it is needed. Is there a problem using setVisibility.progressBar in applyMenuChoice? The problem with using setVisibility.progressBar in PrintStatusTask().execute() is that it crashes the app during runtime.

```
public class Controller extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    ...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.controller);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ...

    private boolean applyMenuChoice(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuStatus:
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            new PrintStatusTask().execute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ...
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
new PrintStatusTask().execute();
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This is what you are doing:
1.  Show the progressBar
2.  Spawn a task on a separate thread
3.  Hide the progressBar

This entire process is going to take no more than a couple milliseconds to execute.  You need to hide the progress bar in the `onPostExecute()` method of the PrintStatusTask class.

You need to understand that the `execute()` method of [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a call that executes another thread and doesn't wait for it to finish.  That's kind of the whole point of AsyncTask.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. That was it. I also needed to put the setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) in the onPreExecute(). bleh!

Comment: Is progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); the best way to remove a progressBar? I hope animation stops in this case and doesn't eat performance...

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to hide the `ProgressBar` in the `AsyncTask`? If so, it must be done in `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute` (like all UI commands).

Also, use something like this:

```
private void toggleProgressBar() {
    switch (progressBar.getVisibility()) {
    case View.GONE:
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    default:
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        break;
    }
}
```